# Saving progress in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

im new in vb.net so go easy on me. How can i save progress in vb.net? to make it short, i give an example. i have 100 checkbox, 100 text box. with a save button and submit button. What should i use to WHEN save button is used. When save button i clicked, all the checkboxes that has been checked and all the value of the textboxes can be save progress then he/she can continue it when he log in again. One of my friend said, save it in sql. But it is to much many if im ganna use sql. any advice on which im ganna use?

Comment: text file with program. That's the easiest way for me.

Comment: Text file program? Can you explain more. Thanks. I don't know that yet

Comment: I don't know much about vb.net but check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2  This is about reading and writing to text file using code. Warning: This method works only for offline. It shouldn't be use online because the text file shouldn't be accesscible to other users. If you use this for a web-login purpose , you have no choice but sql.

Comment: My project is for web-based intranet.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your friend is correct. the best solution will probably be to save the data entered into a database. It doesn't even have to be a lot of work, since you can use techniques such as data-binding to make you database connection easy.

Comment: Even all the checkboxes and radio buttons that has been checked can be saved?

Comment: Yes. Just out of curiosity, how did you end up with such a large number of elements for the user to fill in? it doesn't seem to be very user-friendly to have a 100 checkboxes and a 100 textboxes on the screen

Comment: its not actually 100, but near 100, it is a listed items of achievements that you should check. the achievements that you have gain in you school.